# Looped file array not uploading all files

Tags: php, file, for-loop, file-upload

I am attempting to upload anywhere from 1 - x amount of files, based on what the user uploads. Recently, I created a for loop to go through the files. What I am seeing is only the first file uploads.

Does anyone see why only the first file would be uploading?

```
class fileUpload
{

    public function __construct()
    {}
    public function upload() {

        $file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
        //$file_count = count($_FILES($file_post['name']));

        for ($i = 0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
//          echo $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index] . "\n";

            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));        

            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                return 0;
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                    return basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Form input:

`<input type="file" name="uploadedFile[]" class="inputfile" id="uploadedFileTest" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple>`

Comment: Please also show your form, how are you submitting the form, and are you saying that the error index in not 0 in the other ones?

Comment: Input added to the question. I am not getting any logged errors while uploading. The additional files, after first file uploads doesn't move to the uploads folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you use the `return`, the `return` will get you out the function and you will get only the first item uploaded.

A simple fix would be:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
    return 0;
}
```

//update 2 suggestion for a solution

```
public function upload() {

        $file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
        //$file_count = count($_FILES($file_post['name']));
            // add a array to save the basename on each loop
            $results = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
//          echo $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index] . "\n";

            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));        

            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                return 0;
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                    $results[] = basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        //return all basename in one shot
        return $results;

    }
```

Comment: `continue` might be more appropriate depending on if OP wants to continue processing the other uploads.

Comment: Well, I need the return value for other matters later on. How could I return after it has fully ran?

Comment: You can push the result of each loop in a array and return at the end of loops this array.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was definitely over-thinking it for some reason. The files now upload correctly. However, I am receiving an error notice and there is a piece of code later in my file that is now just reading "results" instead of the filename. This piece of code" `$fu = new fileUpload();
  $filename = $fu->upload();
  $template = str_replace("{filename}", "A file was uploaded. You can download the file from: <a href='php/uploads/{$filename}'>{$filename}</a>", $template);` Just reads as "Results" and links to a page called that. How do I get the actual filename to popualte?

Comment: Then this is the error that is populating for the line of `return results;` `Notice: Use of undefined constant results - assumed 'results' in`

Comment: it's my bad, i forget the $ before results :)

Comment: Thanks. How could I avoid an array to string conversion in this part of the code though? I know I can use the function join, but I have never done so with calling a function. `$fu = new fileUpload();
  $filename = $fu->upload();
  $template = str_replace("{filename}"`